# How to update the list which is having dictionary data?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, keyvaluepair

Here is the list which is having dictionary data:

```
Fruits = [{'Apple':'10','Banana':'20','Orange':'40'}]
```

I need to update the list by adding 'Grapes':'60'.

**Expected Output**

```
Fruits = [{'Apple':'10','Banana':'20','Orange':'40','Grapes':'60'}]
```

How can I do that?.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is a single dict in the list, you can access it via index and add the appropriate key-value pair:

```
Fruits = [{'Apple':'10','Banana':'20','Orange':'40'}]

# add 'Grapes': '60' to existing dict    
Fruits[0]['Grapes'] = '60'

print(Fruits)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'Apple': '10', 'Banana': '20', 'Orange': '40', 'Grapes': '60'}]
```